# Looking for similar posts plugin with custom tuning

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am using [Similarity](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/similarity/) by David Miller; it is nice, but it misses some features.

I would like to:

- Assign more "weight" on some specific posts (specify them by ID is ok)
- Assign more "weight" to most recent posts (the plugin that I am using it prefers many times very old posts based on tag/category than recent)

Do you known if it exists a plugin with these features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/ might help..

Comment: I like it too. (needs tweaking though)

Comment: @Tal It is a great plugin. The ability to tweak it and make it behave anyway you want make it even better...